# Input string was not in a correct format while reading date from excel

Tags: c#, excel, date

I am trying to upload an excel sheet. Now I am getting an error for the date column. I was able to fix it up to this point base on some suggestions here.  This is the date format on the excel 20/4/2020

But I couldn't figure it out from this point. I kept getting. I was able to get the Value from the excel sheet and stored in **string date**

> Input string was not in a correct format.
>   at System.Number.ThrowOverflowOrFormatException(ParsingStatus status,
>   TypeCode type)    at System.Double.Parse(String s)

Here is my code below

```
//be on the first column [r,c]
int row = 2;
for (int i = 2; i <= noOfRow; i++)   //start from the second row
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(workSheet.Cells[i, 3].Text))
    {
        string date = workSheet.Cells[i, 3].Value.ToString();

        try
        {
            double d = double.Parse(date);//Error is coming from here
            DateTime conv = DateTime.FromOADate(d);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {}
    }
}
```

I will appreciate if someone can help me out
Thanks

Comment: What value does `date` variable have when exception is thrown?

Comment: The string variable is string date = "11/5/2020"

Comment: How about `DateTime.Parse(date);` ?

Comment: @YosefBernal The error was caught from that line  ```double d = DateTime.Parse(date)``` so there is nothing in the ```d``` variable

Comment: I am uncertain how you expect the string '11/5/2020' to be parsed to an double. Parsing numbers, the only character allowed besides numbers is '.'

Comment: I think that it is obvious that `double.Parse("11/5/2020)"` is incorrect statement and therefore it throws an exception, isn't it? You should use `DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact("11/5/2020", "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`. Look at this demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/PTTbd6.

Comment: `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(workSheet.Cells[i, 3].Text))` then your string isn't empty, but it doesn't mean its valid. you can test it `DateTime.TryParse(workSheet.Cells[i, 3].Text, out DateTime date);`

Comment: @IliarTurdushev The variable ```d``` here ```DateTime.FromOADate(d);``` gave this error  ```(local variable) Date d 
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.DateTime' to 'double```

Comment: If you use `DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact("11/5/2020", "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` then you don't need the line `DateTime conv = DateTime.FromOADate(d);` (this line must be deleted or commented). Required date now is in the variable `d`.

Comment: @IliarTurdushev it works. Thanks. Can you put in this in the ```Answer Your Question``` so I can vote it for you.  Thanks, everyone for your contribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs because value in the variable `date = "11/5/2020"` is not a `double` value. It is a `DateTime` value. To fix you problem you should use the next code to convert value in the `date` variable into `DateTime` value:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Method [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netcore-3.1#System_DateTime_ParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) allows you to set the format of the parsed date.

---

> The above code worked for me the day you shared with me. But now I am
>   getting this error `{"String '6/3/2020 12:00:00 AM' was not recognized
>   as a valid DateTime."}` I have tried implementing almost everything on
>   stackoverflow.

If date string in your excel file can be in different formats, then you can use overload of the method [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netcore-3.1#System_DateTime_ParseExact_System_String_System_String___System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_) that supports specifying several parse formats. For example:

```
string[] formats = {"d/M/yyyy", "d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"};
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(date, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Here is [complete sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/t1wnOq) that demostrates this overload of the method `DateTime.ParseExact`.

Comment: The above code worked for me the day you shared with me. But now I am getting this error ```{"String '6/3/2020 12:00:00 AM' was not recognized as a valid DateTime."}```  I have tried implementing almost everything on stackoverflow.