# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime in asp.net core 3

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-core

The date format in an excel upload is returning this error.

`{"String '6/3/2020 12:00:00 AM' was not recognized as a valid DateTime."}`

I was able to fix the issue before [here on stackoverflow(Check code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61747824/input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format-while-reading-date-from-excel/61748875#61748875) but today while testing the upload again, the problem persists. I have checked almost all the suggestions available on StackOverflow but none seem to be working.

On the excel sheet I have `6/3/2020` but in the code I got `6/3/2020 12:00:00 AM`

I have been trying to fix this all day

```
 for (int i = 2; i <= noOfRow; i++)   //start from the second row
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(workSheet.Cells[i, 3].Text))
                {
                    var date = workSheet.Cells[i, 3].Value.ToString();
                    //will throw exception if the fields in tenor are invalid
                    try
                    {

                        DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "M/d/yyyy HH:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        validationResult.Message = "Invalid Date.";
                        validationResult.IsValid = false;
                        validationResult.ErrorRowIndex = row;
                        logger.Error(validationResult.Message);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    validationResult.Message = "Empty Date.";
                    validationResult.IsValid = false;
                    validationResult.ErrorRowIndex = row;
                    logger.Error(validationResult.Message);
                    break;
                }

                ++row;

            }

            return validationResult;
        }
```

Comment: how are you converting to datetime? you can do like this DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("stringValue", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: Please post your code - that string converts fine if using DateTime.Parse

Comment: When you import to SQL Server from Excel, the importer picks a default data type for each field you are importing. Check to make sure that a) the data type of your column in Excel is DateTime (I believe it is, based on your post); and b) you have DateTime selected as the field data type in SQL Server during your import. (This applies to manual import process only. For programmatic imports, you will have to make sure you are converting the Excel string into a DateTime object.)

Comment: The code has been updated

Comment: @RobJarvis why am I getting ```6/3/2020 12:00:00 AM``` but what is on the excel sheet is 6/3/2020

Comment: That's because Excel has separate data storage and data display formats. You can change how Excel displays dates, numbers, etc., without changing the underlying data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here's your line of code:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "M/d/yyyy HH:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

And here is the date string you are trying to convert:

```
"6/3/2020 12:00:00 AM"
```

Notice how the date string contains hours, minutes, and seconds, but your format string only has hours and minutes. `DateTime.ParseExact` needs you to supply the exact format of the incoming string.

Answer (score 0):

Try add seconds to format of date:

Replace

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

with

```
    DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```